# TCP/IP connection lost after Windows update in .net4 client - server app

Tags: windows, .net-4.0, tcp, auto-update

I have a .net 4 client/srever app, in which I use standard .net classes for the communication. This app works 24/24 every day.

It works great, but after every Windows update TCP connection between client and server is lost. Some weeks ago I turned off windows updating to investigate this, and so far I did not have this problem. After turning on again, last night I had a Win update and my TCP connection lost again.

I know, it is very strange. What can be the solution? Or what could be the exact reason of this?

Thanks!

Comment: Most Windows updates perform an automatic reboot.